# How can current flowing in a cylindrical conductor exert pressure on its walls?

Tags: electric-current

Shouldn't it be zero as the electrons so not hit the walls at all?

Comment: Please ask a specific question. You have not asked anything at all. The question as such makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is a result of magnetic forces and is called the [Pinch Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)). It is the same effect as the [attraction between two wires carrying currents in the same direction](https://www.boundless.com/physics/textbooks/boundless-physics-textbook/magnetism-21/magnetic-fields-magnetic-forces-and-conductors-159/magnetic-force-between-two-parallel-conductors-563-6223/). Each "filament" of current acts as a separate wire, exerting a magnetic force on other filaments, "pinching" or squeezing them together.

Comment: The OP asked about the force on the wall of the cylinder, not the current itself. Either way the question is unclear.

Comment: @Lelouch : All questions require some interpretation. If the OP understood exactly what he/she was asking about, there would be no need to ask.